# Writing a function with text arguments

Tags: r, function

I have a matrix (colormatrix) that in the first column (called NCS.code) has a identifier, and in a second column (called colour.assignment) that has color names.

I would like to create a function (changecolor) that can change the color name (so the value of colour.assignment), based on the identifier name. I wrote the following, but it does not work.

```
changecolor<-function(id,color){
locdat<-match(id, colormatrix$NCS.code)
#finds the location where id matches the identifier
colormatrix_lab$colour.assignment[locdat]<-color}
#changes the color name at location locdat into the name that was given as input
changecolor("S0300-N","white")
#test if the code works -- which is not the case.
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can I suggest not using `<<-`, and instead outputting the modified matrix. Your call would look like this: `newmatrix <- changecolor(oldmatrix, "S0300-N","white")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to modify global variables from within function calls, you can not use `<-` because it will not evaluate in the global scope. To do what you want - try using:
`<<-` when modifying global data structures from within function calls.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was not aware of this problem -- I'll look it up.

Comment: Just be careful when using `<<-`. Because of its sideeffects (modifying objects in the calling environment) it makes predicting the behaviour of your code harder.